# 405 Method Not Allowed Error when making a JSON API request from a simple create-react-app

Tags: 8

The following request is giving me a 405 Method not allowed when running from a simple create-react-app generated project from localhost:3000. I really need this app to run outside of the domain (decoupled). This feels very much like a cross origin issue but I'm sending the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header token and have apache configured to accept the headers as well.

No idea what I'm doing wrong...

```
Host: contenta.loc
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,x-csrf-token
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

However, running the same code from within a custom module on the same domain executes as expected.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Querystring from 'query-string';
import SubRequests from 'd8-subrequests';

const URL = 'http://contenta.loc';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
      csrfToken: '',
      oauthToken: {}
  };

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.initializeCsrfToken();
    this.initializeOauthToken();
  }

  initializeCsrfToken(){
    axios.get(URL + '/session/token')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({csrfToken: response.data});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error ' + error);
    });
  }

  initializeOauthToken(){
    const data = {
      grant_type: 'password',
      client_id: '77e40506-4b2a-4317-b6c0-5ed5b27ce886',
      client_secret: 'test1123',
      username: 'test',
      password: 'test'
    };

    axios.post(URL + '/oauth/token', Querystring.stringify(data))
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({oauthToken: response.data.access_token});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error ' + error);
      });
  }


  fetchSubrequests() {
    const subrequests = new SubRequests(URL + '/subrequests?_format=json');
    const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(this.state.oauthToken);

    subrequests.add({
      uri: '/api/categories'
    });

    subrequests.add({
      uri: '/api/tags'
    });
    subrequests.add({
      uri: '/api/menus'
    });

    axios.get(subrequests.getUrl(), {
      headers: {
        Authorization: AuthStr,
        'X-CSRF-Token': this.state.csrfToken,
      }
    }).then(dataresponse => {
      console.log(dataresponse);
    })

  }

  render = () => {
    return ( 
      <button >
        <div onClick ={
          () => {this.fetchSubrequests()}
        } > Fetch Subrequests</div> 
      </button>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

---

---

UPDATE:

Here's what my `services.yml` cors.config looked like: (THIS IS WRONG???)

```
   # Configure Cross-Site HTTP requests (CORS).
   # Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
   # for more information about the topic in general.
   # Note: By default the configuration is disabled.
  cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: ['x-csrf-token,authorization,content-type,accept,origin,x-requested-with']
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: ['POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT']
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['*']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: true
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: false
```

This is what my cors.config needs to be for it to work!!

```
cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    # ['x-csrf-token,authorization,content-type,accept,origin,x-requested-with']
    allowedHeaders: ['*']
      # - '*'
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    # ['POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT']
    allowedMethods: ['*']
    #  - '*'
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['*']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: true
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: false
```

Here's what my `apache.conf` looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName loc
  DocumentRoot /Users/justinwinter/Sites
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/justinwinter/Sites/%-2/docroot
  UseCanonicalName Off
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization"

  <Directory "/Users/justinwinter/Sites/*/docroot">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**NOT WORKING FROM A SEPARATE JS REACT APP**

The following screenshot shows the result of running the same JS from within the contenta.loc domain (same server as the endpoint)

[image: Drupal Custom Module Implementation]

**WORKING FROM WITHIN A CUSTOM MODULE**

The following screenshot shows the error when running the JS from within the create-react-app nodejs localhost server.

[image: 405 (Method Not Allowed)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable CORS support modifying the sites/default/services.yml file

```
cors.config:
enabled: true
allowedHeaders:
  - '*'
allowedMethods:
  - '*'
allowedOrigins:
   # Note: you need to specify the host + port where your app will run.
  - localhost:8000
exposedHeaders: false
maxAge: false
supportsCredentials: false
```

Comment: See my cors.config above - forgot to add that before. I I'll try specifying the default host and port though and see if that helps. Funny as I seem to have run into this same thing previously here: 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2715637

Comment: Whoa... Seems that specifying the allowedHeaders like this: `['x-csrf-token,authorization,content-type,accept,origin,x-requested-with']` was causing the cors to fail... I don't know how many times I will be bitten by this issue... :( 

What would production settings look like for allowedHeaders and methods?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try `['x-csrf-token', 'authorization', 'content-type', 'accept', 'origin', 'x-requested-with']` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example of `local.services.yml` file which can be placed in the `sites/` folder:

```
# Local development services.
#
# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  cors.config:
      enabled: true
      # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
      allowedHeaders: ['*']
      # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
      allowedMethods: ['*']
      # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
      allowedOrigins: ['*']
      # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
      exposedHeaders: false
      # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
      maxAge: false
      # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
      supportsCredentials: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Check [`sites/default/default.services.yml`](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/default/default.services.yml?h=8.5.x) for example. Check also: [Opt-in CORS support](https://www.drupal.org/node/2715637).

The file should be loaded from your settings file, e.g.

```
/**
 * Enable local development services.
 */
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/local.services.yml';
```

If you're using Apache, check also: [CORS on Apache](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html).